# Using a URL as a URL parameter in Django Rest Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have a model whose unique field is an address. The thing is, I am trying to get instances of this model using AJAX.

```
var address = 'http://example.com/blog/2/';

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://sitemy.com/api/get_content/'+encodeURIComponent(address),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log('Success');
    }
});
```

In my urls.py, I have the following code:

```
url(r'^api/get_content/(?P<url>.+)/$', views.get_content),
```

So I am trying to use this URL pattern to capture the get request. However, I am constantly getting a 404 error since the url sent from the request does not match my pattern. What gives? How can I solve this?

In case its important, in my views, I am doing the following:

```
def get_content(request, address):
    try:
        content = Content.objects.get(address=urllib.unquote(address))
    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ContentSerializer(content)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I welcome any general advice regarding the encoding of URLS, as that just boggles my mind for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: If the unique field is coming from a model instance, can you simply use the `pk` field instead? It will certainly save you the headache.

Comment: nope, has to be a url since its a plugin.